# PHP Laravel show method by another attibute

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using a resourceful route. For the `show()` method, I don't want to find the record via the `id` (primary key) but using the articles `title` instead.

```
public function show($id){

    $article = Article::find($id);

    if(empty($article))
        abort(404);

    return view('articles.show', compact('article'));
}
```

How can I achieve this.

Comment: am try to use 
$articlel =Article::where('title', '=', 1)->firstOrFail();
but not work

Comment: The code you posted in your comment would try to find a record with a title of `1`.

Comment: yes i think so i change to $articlel =Article::where('title', '=', $name)->firstOrFail();

Comment: and $name come form parameter method

Comment: Thats better! Now what errors are you getting? Try to explain in detail what the problem is.

Comment: this is my new code 
public function show($name){

  $articlel =Article::where('title', '=', $name)->firstOrFail();


  if(empty($article))

  abort(404);

  return view('articles.show', compact('article'));

 }

Comment: but it still not work to find data where title=$name

Comment: Unfortunately, "it doesn't work" provides zero information to anyone trying to help you. Check the error logs, enable debug mode, if it's not working there should be an error message being displayed somewhere. If there is no error message, what is happening? Could it be possible an article with that title doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function show($title){

        $article = Article::where('title',$title)->first();

        if(empty($article))

        abort(404);

        return view('articles.show', compact('article'));
    }
```

this code return value same as find